# How to get the tp-link TL-WN723N working on ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

How do I get the tp-link TL-WN723N wireless adapter to work on ubuntu. And also if I do modify it to work, will its stop working in windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/278747/connecting-to-wifi-internet-using-tp-link-tl-wn723n-usb-adapter-with-ubuntu-12

Comment: same problem here and is not the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/278747/connecting-to-wifi-internet-using-tp-link-tl-wn723n-usb-adapter-with-ubuntu-12

Answer (score 5):

Look in the Windows drivers cd:

```
/media/CD176A1/TL-WN725N_WN723N/Driver Files/Windows 7 32bit
```

for the file `netrtwlanu.inf` search for `RTL8188EU`. If you have that do this:

add other drivers on blacklist
sudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist

```
# Blacklist native RealTek 8188CUs drivers
blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist rtlwifi
```

Go here https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Get the zip from  ***Download this repository as a zip*** then:

then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
unzip rtl8188eu-master.zip -x
cd rtl8188eu-master/
```

then do the steps from `README.md`:

```
make
uname -r
```

in my case `3.2.0-43-generic-pae` so I use

```
sudo cp 8188eu.ko /lib/modules/3.2.0-43-generic-pae/kernel/net/wireless/
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8188eu
ifconfig # and you can see the wlan interface :-)
```

if it is not RTL8188EU look in that file and write here as a comment the RTL8... you find there