# TL-WN723N v3 driver install

Tags: wireless, drivers

[How to get the tp-link TL-WN723N working on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296994/how-to-get-the-tp-link-tl-wn723n-working-on-ubuntu)

Sorry for the headache in advance ;), if someone could assume i don't know anything about Linux at all and help me to understand exactly what i need to do.

I can confirm its RTL8188EU, i have downloaded https://github.com/gleb-chipiga/rtl8188eu , and from there i don't know what exactly i'm supposed to be doing.

I don't need a complete guide on what/how to use commands, but i just need an idiots guide to doing this and i can learn quick on my own from there.

EDIT: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal yes, i'm learning, but about as far from %100 as i could be.

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open a terminal and install the prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Now assuming that you downloaded the file rtl8188eu-master.zip to your desktop, right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd Desktop/rtl8188eu-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

If there are any errors, please edit your question to show us so we may troubleshoot.